# How to apply same transform on differrent set of unequal no. of vertices

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, face

I want to apply the transformation from one 3D mesh to another mesh using code (not in meshlab or blender). In my case, I have a 3D face model and a 3D facemask (with vertex and face information).

**3D face model**
[image]

**3D face mask**
[image]

My approach is below:

1. First, get ids of all the vertices from the 3D mask mesh (VA)
2. Get ids of all the vertices from the 3D face-model mesh (VB)
3. Find correspondence vertices to apply the transformation on (VB)
4. Find transformation required to get the same shape

Now, what would be the best way to find the correspondence vertices when the total no. of vertices are not equal in both the mesh.

What would be the right way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For each vertex v in VA, can't you simply find the closest vertex v' in VB, using minimum pairwise distance? Of course VA and VB need to be in the same coordinate system first.

Comment: But my question is What if VA and VB are not equal, then how will I chose the closest vertex

Comment: You calculate all distances between pairs (v, v') and choose the pair with smallest distance?